# Different type of captions

Tags: tables, numbering, captions

I have four tables. The first table has a caption of `Table A: Title`. The other three tables have captions of `Table 1: Title`, `Table 2: Title`, and `Table 3: Title`.

When I use

```
 \caption{Title}
```

it gives me `Table 1: Title`, `Table 2`, `Table 3`, and `Table 4`, but I don't want this format.

Comment: Do you use the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) at all?

Comment: I didnt use any packages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the numbering to `Alph` for the first table, and then change it back to `arabic`. In addition, you need to step the table counter back by one, so that you don't get table A followed by table 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{table}}
%
\begin{table}
\centering\rule{2cm}{2cm} %Replace with tabular
\caption{The first}
\end{table}
%
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
%
\begin{table}
\centering\rule{2cm}{2cm} %Replace with tabular
\caption{The second}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}
\centering\rule{2cm}{2cm} %Replace with tabular
\caption{The third}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was Really helpful I am really thankful :)